# flock without racing conditions in linux shell

Tags: bash, locking, file-descriptor

Source from https://plus.google.com/+RandalLSchwartz/posts/QcrqvT3mUdy

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                       

(
    if ! flock -n -x 200
    then
        echo "$$ cannot get flock"
        exit 0
    fi
    echo "$$ start"
    sleep 10                    # real work would be here                      
    echo "$$ end"
) 200< $0
```

I am having problem understanding this. So flock is claiming exlusive access to fd 200 here,
but what is the () 200< $0 redirection for? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usage of `flock` uses the script file of the executable itself (`$0`) as its own lock file.  Since file locking is based on a mechanism *besides* the contents of the file, this is possible.  Using `<` instead of `>` or `>>` assumes that it already exists and does not need to be created first; since the script typically exists and is readable during its execution (anything else is pathological for sure), this is a safe assumption.

Using `200<` opens `$0` for reading and redirects it to file descriptor 200.  Inside the subshell (formed with the large `( ... )`) the `flock` command then uses this open file descriptor for file locking.

Comment: In this case, isn't it more logical to put the 200< $0 at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Why is a subshell necessary?

Comment: The subshell is the way `flock` is designed to work.  See its man page for details.  The syntax for redirections is build like this; redirections appear _after_ the command.  In this case, the parentheses block of the subshell is the command.

Comment: Is there anything special about the number 200? What if another script is also using this fd?

Comment: You have the numbers from 3 up to 255 available.  Choosing one so you do not run into a clash is a kind of art ;-)  No, to be earnest, 200 is just as valid a choice as 42 would have been or 103.  If a script _inside_ yours is using the same number, then you are in trouble, yes.  Avoid that, that's all.